# Get form of Just-Eat

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, robobrowser

I want to **scrape** forms in Just-Eat but it seems that the form didn't exist !
I use that code :

```
br.open("https://www.just-eat.fr/")
form = br.get_forms()
```

but form didn't detect any form ! But when you go on the code source we can find a form :

```
<form class="search-form autocomplete-target" action="#" id="geolocate_form_home">
```

I don't know how to make it detectable ! Did someone have any idea ?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: this `print(br.parsed)` doesn't show form in source code. But it shows `<iframe>` with url. If I use it then it shows message about blocking bots/scripts.

Comment: if you run `br.open("https://httpbin.org/get")` then `print(br.parsed)` shows that it uses `"User-Agent": "python-requests/2.21.0"` and it can be main problem or first problem.

Answer (score 0):

Server sends page only with `<iframe>` which has message about blocking for security reason.

First problem in `User Agent` header. Normally Python use `python-requests/2.21.0` but server may need `User Agent` used in real browser. For example Firefox on Linux

```
br = robobrowser.RoboBrowser(user_agent='Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i586; rv:31.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0')
```

But it can still sends page with `<iframe>` which has message.

But if I load the same url again then it loads correct page.
Probably now it has all needed cookies and now server doesn't make problems.

If you want you can also load page from `<iframe>` to behave like real human.

```
import robobrowser

br = robobrowser.RoboBrowser(user_agent='Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i586; rv:31.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0')
br.parser = 'lxml'

br.open("https://www.just-eat.fr")
#print(br.parsed)
print(br.get_forms())

#iframe_src = br.select('iframe')[0]['src']
#print(iframe_src)

#br.open("https://www.just-eat.fr"+iframe_src)
#print(br.parsed)

br.open("https://www.just-eat.fr")
#print(br.parsed)
print(br.get_forms())
```